# Proof of ways to put distinct Balls into distinct Boxes

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

So I have learned that the formula for putting m balls into n boxes such that no box is empty is the following:
$$T(m,n)=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{n \choose k}(n-k)^m$$
I am really confused as how to prove this. If someone could please explain it, I would much appreciate it!

Comment: Please clarify your question. Putting m balls into n boxes such that ...

Comment: You forgot to say no box can be empty, otherwise it would simply be $n^m$

Comment: @CarryonSmiling Sorry. My bad!

Comment: Apply Inclusion–exclusion principle. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: Given finite sets A and B, how many surjective functions (onto functions) are there from A to B?

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki A friend had told me to use the inclusion exclusion principle that but I still couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is the number of ways to split $m$ distinct balls into $n$ boxes so that no box is empty (or the number of surjections $f:\{1,2,\dots m\}\rightarrow \{1,2\dots n\}$).

The proof is a simple inclusion/exclusion proof.

Let $A_x$ be the set of functions that don't contain $x$ in the range.

We wish to find $n^m-|A_1\cup A_2\dots \cup A_n|$ (in other words, we want to count how many functions are not surjective).

Because of inclusion exclusion $|A_1\cup A_2\dots \cup A_n|=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\sum\limits_{i_1<i_2\dots<i_k}|A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\dots \cap A_{i_k}|$

Clearly $|A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\dots \cap A_{i_k}|=(n-k)^m$ independently of the actual values of $i_1,i_2\dots i_k$.

So our sum is just $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^m$

Just to finish as smoothly as possible:

$n^m-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^m=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^m$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seeing it written out helps lot. I understand now!

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't think of it like this in my mind. In fact I had to look out the actual formulation for inclusion/exclusion in wikipedia. I always had a sort of vague idea of what it meant, but I always forget the actual correct way to state it.

Comment: Oh, and happy to help. Please tell me if something is confusing.

Comment: Good answer, but I think you want to modify your reference to Stirling numbers and to splitting balls into nonempty parts.

Comment: why?${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Once you split the balls into n nonempty parts, you still have to assign the parts to the boxes; so this gives $\S(m,n)\cdot n!$

Comment: oh yeah, good point